# how to store row numbers of slected rows of a dataframe in shiny through observe function

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm using shiny to create an interactive dashboard with value boxes and some datatables. I want to update the value in the value box through selected rows of a dataframe in shiny output. However I'm able to read the row numbers of selected rows of dataframe but was unable to store them into a list or vector.

[image]

UI.R

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
 dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "NUS Testing"),
    dashboardSidebar(),
    dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      valueBoxOutput("norm")
    ),#ending of first fluid row
    fluidRow(dataTableOutput("table"))
    #fluidRow(verbatimTextOutput("x4"))
   )
   )#ending of dashboard page

))



Server.R
shinyServer(function(input,output,session){
  test=read.csv("test.csv",header = T)

  output$table = DT::renderDataTable(test,server = F)
  output$norm = renderValueBox({
    valueBox(
      paste0(summpg), "Progress", icon = icon("bicycle"),
      color = "aqua"
    )
  }) #ending of valuebox
  summpg=sum(test[,2])  
enter image description here
  x5 = observeEvent(input$table_rows_selected,{
    str(input$table_rows_selected)
  })

  #reading the data from observe event

}) #ending of shinyserver function
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try creating a reactive expression with summpg? The following should work:

```
summpg <- reactive({
    sum(test[input$table_rows_selected, 2])
})
```

Note that this makes `summpg` into a reactive function so you need to refer it as `summpg()` (with parentheses) elsewhere. `reactive` is necessary if you want the sum to update whenever the selected rows change.